# push notification ontap handle not working in flutter iOS and android when app is in kill state

Tags: flutter, dart, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

push notification on-tap handle not working in flutter iOS and android when app is in kill/terminated state.
Notification are receiving in kill state but on-tap event not working in android & iOS both. Rest all background and foreground & their on-tap event working correctly.

I'm using below function for kill state as per flutter documentation but after tapping on notification, this function is not working at all.

```
await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage().then((message) {
      showSnackBarWithAnction("please chl ja bhai", _scaffoldKey);
      print("getInitialMessage: $message");
      if(message != null){
        print("intial message");
        // notification tap handle function call
      }
    });
```

please help. Thanks !!